# Google Blacklist Workaround?

Tags: google

I have a WordPress site that google believes to contain malware and as such, they've blacklisted the IP.

The malware has already been removed and I am taking steps to get google to remove the IP from their blacklist; but in the mean time, is it an acceptable solution to purchase a new IP address, then forward my domain name to the new IP address?

The problem is, this particular business is not able to send emails to their customers because google has blacklisted their IP address.  So, is this an acceptable workaround while I meanwhile try to get google to remove their site from their blacklist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Google Safe Browsing keep detecting malware on my website?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98161/why-does-google-safe-browsing-keep-detecting-malware-on-my-website)

Comment: This is more of a question for Google support. You will have to ask them if their blacklist is strictly IP based or if it blocks the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your present domain is blacklisted, Google will consequently suspect (blacklist) any other domain to which it forwards. So it is useless to purchase a new IP address for that purpose.

You have to  do the necessary to request Google to remove your domain from its blacklists and be patient (it can take several weeks even if you have done everything correctly. Reading my [detailed answer here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/98161/why-does-google-safe-browsing-keep-detecting-malware-on-my-website/98179#98179) will let you understand better).

Depending on the activity you are running, I think it is better, *if possible*, to contact your clients directly and inform them of your new domain.