# How Anti Phishing in Google Safe Browsing works?

Tags: phishing, safe-browsing-filter

As the question says, can anybody give insights on how anti phishing works in [Google Safe Browsing](https://www.google.com/transparencyreport/safebrowsing/diagnostic/)?

Does it just use a database of detected phishing URLs or does it use any heuristic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Safe Browsing just checks against a database provided by Google if the visited URL is potentially malicious. There are no heuristics employed by the client using Google Safe Browsing but instead every intelligence is in the crawling and classification process done by Google.

Comment: Thanks. Please can you describe the intelligence in the crawling and classification process done by Google?

Comment: @user5155835: The process is proprietary and not publicly documented. [What tools does the Google safe browsing service rely on?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/65104/what-tools-does-the-google-safe-browsing-service-rely-on) gives some insight into the few known details and [Large-Scale Automatic Classification of Phishing Pages](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/35580.pdf) too.

Comment: Thanks. Please update me if you get any additional information. I've accepted the answer :)